# Laptop used to be unable to run on battery alone, despite it displaying as 90% charged; then it suddenly started working

Tags: laptop, battery, lenovo-laptop

While I am fairly experienced with desktop DIY repair, I have found myself stuck when dealing with my laptop. I have had a strange experience with my Legion Y530-15ICH-1060 battery. About a month back during a visit to the UK, it started to seem like my battery had expired.

The laptop started only working while it was plugged in and removing the charger while the laptop was running would cause it to instantly die. However, the OS would read the battery level as a permanent 90%, this never changed no matter how long it was plugged in, the battery always read 90%. I assumed that I would have to buy a replacement battery.

However, today it has decided to start working normally again. I didn't really do anything to fix the battery over the last month besides running diagnostics with `powercfg /batteryreport`. Of course, I am happy that it seems to be working as normal again, however I am worried about what could have been happening as I tend to try my best to take care of my devices. Does anyone have any insight as to what is/was going on?

Some extra info: my only guess was that there was a difference in power delivery in UK homes as opposed to South Africa where I live. However, after researching, both UK and South Africa have the same power delivery (230V at 50Hz). I can offer the results of `powercfg /batteryreport` if asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(A)** If your battery can hold a reasonable charge, it may need to be reset (certainly something Lenovo does and perhaps other manufacturers as well). Resetting the battery will help it show charge level correctly.

You should have Lenovo Vantage installed.  If not, install it from the Microsoft Store.

Install Vantage and run it.

In the Device, Power Settings, run Battery Gauge Reset.  Follow all the instructions and do the reset as directed (takes a while).

**(B)** Once done, see if you have Battery Threshold management (probably yes).

Do a final restart when the reset is complete.

Set that for 80% and then you can leave AC plugged in without overcharging.

Your battery charging should now look very normal to you.

Comment: Thank you, you have set me on the right track. Unfortunately, for some reason the version of Vantage for the Legion laptops doesn't have the Battery Gauge Reset feature. There do seem to be other ways to get it done so I'll be trying those out.

Comment: It might be there - in Power, scroll down, and the Battery reset is near the bottom. Otherwise try out the other ways.